# Duals of ideals of operators between Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Given an operator ideal $\mathfrak{I}$, $\mathfrak{I}^\text{dual}$ is the class of all operators $A:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $A^*\in \mathfrak{I}$. Given an operator ideal $\mathfrak{I}$, it is often of interest to know when there is another ideal $\mathfrak{J}$ of independent interest such that either $\mathfrak{I}^\text{dual}=\mathfrak{J}$ or $\mathfrak{I}=\mathfrak{J}^\text{dual}$.

Natural examples are the compact and weakly compact operators, which are their own dual ideals. Another interesting example is that an operator $A:X\to Y$ is Asplund (or decomposing) if and only if $A^*$ has the Radon-Nikodym property. Therefore if $\mathfrak{P}$ denotes the ideal of Radon-Nikodym operators and $\mathfrak{D}$ denotes the ideal of Asplund operators, $\mathfrak{P}^\text{dual}=\mathfrak{D}$.

Let $\mathfrak{V}$ denote the class of completely continuous operators and let $\mathfrak{DP}$ denote the ideal of operators $B:X\to Y$ such that for any Banach space $Z$ and any weakly compact operator $A:Y\to Z$, $AB$ is completely continuous.

Is it known whether $\mathfrak{V}^\text{dual}$ or $\mathfrak{DP}^\text{dual}$ is another ideal of independent interest? Or whether there exists another ideal $\mathfrak{I}$ of independent interest such that either $\mathfrak{I}^\text{dual}= \mathfrak{V}$ or $\mathfrak{I}^\text{dual}= \mathfrak{DP}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{K}$, $\mathcal{W}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ denote the compact, weakly compact and completely continuous operators, respectively, and let $\mathcal{W}^{-1}\circ \mathcal{K}$ denote the operators $T:X\to Y$ such that $BT\in\mathcal{K}$ for each $Z$ and each $B\in\mathcal{W}(Y,Z)$.

CLAIM: $\mathcal{C}^{dual} = \mathcal{W}^{-1}\circ \mathcal{K}$.

Suppose $T\in \mathcal{C}^{dual}(X,Y)$. 
If $B\in\mathcal{W}(Y,Z)$, then $(BT)^*=T^*B^* \in \mathcal{K}$ because $T^*\in \mathcal{C}$ and $B^*\in\mathcal{W}$, hence $BT\in \mathcal{K}$, and we conclude $T\in\mathcal{W}^{-1}\circ \mathcal{K}$.

Suppose $T\in (\mathcal{W}^{-1}\circ \mathcal{K})(X,Y)$, and let $(g_n)$ be a weakly null sequence in $Y^*$. 
The operator $B:Y\to c_0$ defined by $Bx =(g_n(x))$ is weakly compact. Then $BT\in \mathcal{K}$. Since the unit vector basis $(e_n)$ is weak$^*$-null in $\ell_1=c_0^*$, $(T^*g_n)= (T^*B^*e_n)$ is norm null. Thus $T^*\in \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

An operator $T:X\to Y$ is **Banach-Saks** if for every bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ there is a subsequence $(Tx_{n_k})$ such that the Cesàro means $N^{-1}(\sum_{k=1}^N Tx_k)$ from a norm-convergent subsequence. 
The class of Banach-Saks operators  $\mathcal{BS}$ is an operator ideal which is contained in the operator ideal of weakly compact operators. 
In particular, if the identity $I_E$ of a Banach space $E$ is in $\mathcal{BS}$ then $E$ is reflexive.

In the paper [[Ann. Acad. Sci. Fennicae Math. 18 (1993), 3-11]](https://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol18/gonzalez.pdf), it is proved that $T:X\to Y$ is $\mathcal{BS}$ if and only if the intermediate space $E$ in the Davis-Figiel-Johnson-Pelczynski factorization of $T$ has the Banach-Saks property (i.e. $I_E\in \mathcal{BS}$), $T^* \in \mathcal{BS}$ if and only if $I_{E^*}\in \mathcal{BS}$, and $T^{**} \in \mathcal{BS}$ if and only if $I_{E^{**}}\in \mathcal{BS}$. Since $I_E\in \mathcal{BS}$ does not imply $I_{E^*}\in \mathcal{BS}$, we get:

$\mathcal{BS}^{dual}\neq \mathcal{BS}$, and $\mathcal{BS}^{dual\, dual}= \mathcal{BS}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't address the question, which is asking specifically about the two ideals $\mathfrak{V}$ and $\mathfrak{DP}$.

Comment: For every countable, non-zero ordinal $\xi$, the notion of $\xi$-Banach-Saks has been defined by Argyros, Merkourakis, and Tsarpalias, and $1$-Banach-Saks coincides with the Banach-Saks property. It was shown by Beanland and Causey that for every $0<\xi<\omega_1$, the $\xi$-analogue of the result you mention holds.

Comment: A Banach space $E$ has the Dunford-Pettis property and contains no copies of $\ell_1$ if and only if the dual space $E^*$ has the Schur property.

Comment: Do you know if $\mathcal{DP}\cap\mathcal{R}  = \mathcal{B}^{dual}$? Here $\mathcal{R}$ are the operators that factor through a Banach space containing no copies of $\ell_1$.

Comment: I can see two of the three requisite implications to show that $\mathfrak{DP}\cap \mathfrak{R}= \mathfrak{V}^\text{dual}$. Do you have a reference for the fact: A Banach space $E$ has the DPP and contains no copies of $\ell_1$ if and only if $E^*$ has the Schur property?

Comment: A reference for that fact is J. Diestel, "A survey or results related to the Dunford–Pettis property" , Contemp. Math. , 2 , Amer. Math. Soc. (1980) pp. 15–60. The proof is not difficult.

Comment: Suppose that E has the DPP and contains no copies of $\ell_1$. Let $(f_n)$ be a weakly null sequence in $E^*$. We have to show that $(f_n)$ converges in norm to $0$.

Comment: The operator $T:E\to c_0$ defined by $Tx =(f_n(x))$ is weakly compact.

Comment: Since $E$ has the Dunford-Pettis property, $T$ is completely continuous. But $E$ contains no copies of $\ell_1$ implies that every bounded sequence in $E$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence. Then $T$ is compact. Hence $(f_n)$ converges in norm to $0$.

Comment: Suppose that $E^*$ is Schur. Then $E^*$ has the DPP, hence $E$ has the DPP. Moreover, if a space contains a copy of $\ell_1$ then it has a quoptient isomorphic to $\ell_2$, hence the dual contains a copy of $\ell_2$, thus the dual is not Schur.

Comment: I was unaware of the fact that a space having an $\ell_1$ subspace must have an $\ell_2$ quotient. Do you have a reference or proof of this fact? 

I don't have access to the Diestel survey.

Comment: It appears as 4.16 Corollary in the book [Joe Diestel, Hans Jarchow, Andrew Tonge. Absolutely Summing Operators. Cambridge Univ. Press, 1995].

Comment: One can show that $\mathfrak{V}^\text{dual}\subset \mathfrak{DP}\cap \mathfrak{R}$, but the reverse inclusion does not hold. A characterization of being in $\mathfrak{DP}$ (analogous to the spatial case) is: $A:X\to Y \in \mathfrak{DP}$ if and only if for any weakly null $(x_i)$ in $X$ and any weakly null $(y^*_i)$ in $Y^*$, $\lim_i y^*_i(Ax_i)=0$. If $A^*$ is completely continuous, $(x_i)$ is weakly null, and $(y^*_i)$ is weakly null, then $(A^*y^*_i)$ is norm null and $(x_i)$ is bounded, so $\lim_i A^*y^*_i(x_i)=\lim_i y^*_i(Ax_i)=0$, and $A$ lies in $\mathfrak{DP}$.

Comment: If $A:X\to Y$ is not in $\mathfrak{R}$, there is a subspace $E$ of $X$ such that $E, F:=A(E)$ are isomorphic to $\ell_1$ and $A|_E:E\to F$ is an isomorphism. There exists a subspace $G$ of $F$ such that $E/G$ is isomorphic to $\ell_2$ and the quotient map $q:F\to F/G$ is in $\Pi_2$. By the $\Pi_2$ lifting property, there exists a surjection $Q:Y\to F/G$. This is weakly compact, since $F/G$ is reflexive.

Comment: Then $QA:X\to F/G$ is also a surjection ($A$ maps $E$ onto $F$, which is mapped onto $F/G$ by $Q|_F=q$).  Then $QA$, and therefore $A^*Q^*$, is not compact. Since $Q^*$ is weakly compact, $A^*$ isn't completely continuous, or else $A^*Q^*$ would be compact. 

Therefore if $A^*$ is completely continuous, $A\in \mathfrak{R}$.

Comment: However, the formal identity from $\ell_1$ to $\ell_2$ lies in $\mathfrak{DP}\cap \mathfrak{R}$ and not in $\mathfrak{V}^\text{dual}$ since $I_{\ell_1}\in  \mathfrak{DP}$ and $I_{\ell_2}\in \mathfrak{R}$. But the adjoint of the formal identity maps the weakly null $\ell_2$ basis to a normalized sequence in $\ell_\infty$, and is therefore not completely continuous.

Comment: OK: $\mathcal{C}^{dual}\subsetneq \mathcal{DP}\cap\mathcal{R}$.